# Magento downloadable files location after purchase?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have a Magento 1.4 downloadable store.

My downloadable files are hosted on Amazon S3.  The products link directly to the files Amazon S3.

After a customer makes a purchase, how does Magento distribute the file?

1. Will the customer download via the original, source link on Amazon
   S3?
2. Or is the order file transferred to the website server on a file by
   file basis?  Possibly in the var folder?

Confused by this, searched here and also google without any luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my local copy of CE, my uploaded downloadable files show up under `/media/downloadable/files/links/*`

For example, I uploaded a file called `beach.jpg` as a Downloadable product.  It showed up under `/media/downloadable/files/links/b/e/beach_1.jpg`

hth